# JQuery's ajaxForm submits on click, but not on space

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

[JQuery](http://jquery.com)'s well known and loved plugin [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) modifies the form to be submitted by ajax.

I've gotten this to work correctly, including callback functions. What I found broken is that in many cases instead of hitting enter, I hit `tab space` combination. This is useful in cases of filling out textareas, or just because it's faster than reaching for the mouse.

In my implementation clicking the submit button works as expected, but hitting tab, space - does nothing. Form doesn't submit, page doesn't refresh.

I don't know what causes this, or how I would go about debugging it. Please help :)

**Browser Info**:
*Ubuntu* 10.04 
FireFox 3.6.18 fails
google-chrome 12.0.742.112 fails

*Windows* 7
Firefox 3.6.15 fails
Chrome 12.0.742.112 fails
Internet Explorer 9.0.8080.16413 - works as expected.

Comment: Does it behave the same way across all browsers? Are you sure the submit button is highlighted when you press space?

Comment: It worked for me; and the page shouldn't refresh anyway -- that's the point.

Comment: @`Trevor` The button is definitely highlighted. Updated my post with browser info

Comment: @`wanovak` I stated that it doesn't refresh to point out that the code that takes over the default submit behavior is doing something.

Comment: @Mikhail What version of FF are you running? FF latest and Chrome latest are not exhibiting the aforementioned bug for me. What operating system are you running, and what plugins do you have for FF and Chrome?

Comment: @`wanovak` I don't use any plugins except firebug on both FF

Comment: Tab+space triggers a click event just the same as a mouse click. (Even pressing enter on some form field does.) Maybe one of your own event handlers conflicts with the plugin?

Comment: I've not really heard of Tab+Space.  I usually use Tab+Enter.  Does that work?

Comment: @`Milimetric` Tab+Enter works...

Comment: @`Tgr` maybe... how would I debug that?

Comment: Do you mean press Tab out of the textarea then press Space to push the submit button? That depends on the tabIndex attribute of the submit button and the last textarea. Plz put some code that fails ajaxForm.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible causes that I can think of are:

1. Pressing space on the button does not trigger a "click" action/event.
2. Some other handler intercepts the clicking event. E.g. make sure you don't use both `ajaxSubmit` and `ajaxForm` on the same form.

For 2, you can visually check with [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), a plugin for FF.

For 1, you may need to step into the actually code of the plugin, i.e. `jquery.form.js`. Depending which method you use for the form; if `ajaxSubmit`, set a breakpoint around line 290 (`doSubmit`); if `ajaxForm`, around line 589 and 594.

I hope that helps you in debugging the error.

If you found out it is the first case, you may need to attach a keypress handler for the button and simulate the same behaviour across browsers:

```
$('#submitButton').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 32)  // space bar pressed
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your own click handler to the submit button and put in a test alert to see if that fires.

If that works you could call submit on the form yourself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, GTK+ doesn't trigger click on spacebar. Also, spacebar is usually tied to page scroll (by most broswers) so it may not trigger a click by default.

One fix is to bind a `keypress` on the document and manually trigger a `click` or form `submit`.

```
$(document).die('keypress.spacebar').live('keypress.spacebar', function() {
   // do nothing if not spacebar
   if(e.which != 32) { return; };

   var button = $('#mySubmitButton')[0];
   // check if submit button has focus. if not, return
   if(button !== document.activeElement) {
       return;
   }

   // else, go ahead and submit form
   $('#myform').submit();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

*Note* that I'm using namespaced event to avoid any conflicts with any other `keypress` event handler on the form.

Comment: In your solution I'd have to do this for every single form on the page... When i'm done typing this comment i'm gonna hit Tab, Space and it will work the same as clicking Add Comment

Comment: Triggering a click is how form submitting is done. Some user action happens, the browser decides it should trigger a click event, the default action of a click event on the submit button is triggering a submit event on the form, and the default action of that event is to actually submit the form. Perhaps some browsers do not submit forms when the user presses supace on the button, but I would be very surprised to hear of a browser which does submit, but does not trigger a click. It should have a second, completely different method for initiating form submits, which sounds unlikely.

Comment: @Tgr: You're right and as you said, my guess would be that browsers may not submit on space too. GTK+ didn't trigger click on spacebar, this was at the OS level, not at the browser level. Not sure if this has changed.